# Изменение интерфейса уже готового приложения

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Есть у меня серьезная проблема, которая мешает адекватно пользоваться моим телефоном: не работает вся левая часть тачскрина шириной примерно в 1 см. Через adb и команду `wm overscan` я, так сказать, уменьшил экран слева на 100 пикселей. После этого некоторые важные приложения, особенно клавиатура, будто бы не замечают этого и не подстраивают свой интерфейс под новую ширину. А точнее с их дизайном может твориться что-то странное, к примеру элементы интерфейса налезают друг на друга и прочее.

Я решил вручную изменить ширину этой клавиатуры. Залезаю в приложение с помощью `ApkEditor`, иду в папку `layout` и вижу список `xml` файлов, которые отвечают за интерфейс

[image: xml файлы]

Какой именно из них отвечает за отображение клавиатуры я не разобрался, но структура одного из них выглядит так

[image: Один из xml файлов]

Как мне сделать то, что я хочу? Или может есть другой способ уменьшить экран слева?

Comment: Это гениально..

Answer (score 0):

За отступ слева отвечает параметр layout_marginLeft
Попробуйте добавить в корневой LinearLayout

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
```